# what does this logged text means, some ip tried hack my server

Tags: 16.04, server, log, webserver, hacking

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04 and running a small server on it.
When I checked log files with grep -r 'ip-address' /var/log/ command, it returned this log

```
/var/log/auth.log:Dec 19 00:26:00 ip-10-xx-xx-xx sudo: adminuser : TTY=pts/1 ; PWD=/home/adminuser ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/bin/grep -r xx-xx-xx-xx(ipAddress) ./tomcat8 ./catalina.out ./install ./xvdf ./xvdg
/var/log/auth.log:Dec 19 00:26:00 ip-10-xx-xx-xx sudo: adminuser : TTY=pts/1 ; PWD=/home/adminuser ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/bin/grep -r xx-xx-xx-xx(ipAddress) /bin /boot /dev /etc /home /initrd.img /initrd.img.old /lib /lib64 /lost+found /media /mnt /opt /proc /root /run /sbin /snap /srv /sys /tmp /usr /var /vmlinuz /vmlinuz.old
/var/log/apache2/access.log.1:xx-xx-xx-xx(ipAddress) - - [18/Dec/2018:11:20:07 +0900] "\x16\x03\x01\x02" 400 0 "-" "-"
/var/log/apache2/access.log.1:xx-xx-xx-xx(ipAddress) - - [19/Dec/2018:05:52:37 +0900] "GET //recordings/ HTTP/1.1" 302 557 "-" "python-requests/2.6.0 CPython/2.7.5 Linux/3.10.0-862.14.4.el7.x86_64"
```

what does it means? Are they tried to login with `adminuser` as user name and run encrypt files below thees directories?

Comment: The two lines from `auth.log` look like they are caused by your `grep` command.

Comment: FWIW the [10.X.Y.Z address space is non-routable](https://stackoverflow.com/a/528575/383694), ie it's from your own LAN, I'd guess it's the machine you're grepping from. Also ["\x16\x03\x01\x02" appears to arise](https://serverfault.com/questions/390013/http-requests-x80z-x01-x03-x01-in-my-apache-logs) when someone tries to access using SSL a web server that's not using it, so they send https requests to a port that's serving http only.